# Bootstrap Navbar Ruby on Rail, image and text links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Totally new to Ruby on Rails, but I couldn't find the answer, probably because I'm using the wrong keywords, but anyway:

I'm trying to setup a navbar, if I implement a logo 36px high, the buttons/text links stay on top of the page and that container doesn't stretch.

I used the following header:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">

             <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>

          <a class="brand" href="/"> <img src="assets/appiclife.png"></a>


               <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">

                        <li>
                            <%= link_to 'Home',  root_path %>
                        </li>
                        <li>    
                            <%= link_to 'About',  about_path %>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                                <li><%= link_to 'Login',  '#' %></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks like this:
[image]

How can I center those links and stretch the container they're in?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, I needed to add this to the pages.css:

```
.navbar .nav > li > a {
      padding:15px 10px 15px
    }
```